# Reload Catalyst FCGI

Tags: perl, fastcgi, exit, catalyst

I want to reload all Perl modules which our Catalyst application consists of, when we call our FCGI script with `?xxx=yyy` parameter.

To reload I should use `exit;`, right?

What is the easiest way to detect URLs with `?xxx=yyy` using Catalyst?

Comment: If I call `exit;` after `$c->response->body("Stop called!");` then Internal Server Error happens. My crude hack is to use `print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\nStop called!"; exit;`

Comment: Reloading modules usually results in various hard to detect problem. Your example shows that you might not want a reload, but exit and restart the server. Is this what you want?

Comment: I want my FastCGI script to restart, yes

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate because there is a very good answer on how to build an actual restarting script for FastCGI and Catalyst. But it's not using the URL parameter you want, which is a very insecure approach. You don't want anyone to accidentally stumble across this and restarting your server. One could write a script that constantly restarts your app, rendering it unusable. That would not be very desirable. A better approach would be to build a deployment scrpit that does that for you whenever you update your files.